# How can I change title dynamically in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change the title.

Below is my source code.

```py
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Title')
    root.geometry('300x160')
    root.resizable(False,False)
    .
    .
    .
    root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Just call `root.title(...)` whenever you want to change the title.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a string variable.

```
import tkinter as tk
w=tk.Tk()
title='my_title'
w.title(title)
w.mainloop()
```

as I understand you want  it to change automatically. Instead of 'my_title' you can use a user input or data from database.

Quick example with input:

```
import tkinter as tk
i=input('title is: ')
if i:
    w=tk.Tk()
    w.title(i)
    w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Walrus to rescue. Using Python 3.8+

```
import tkinter as tk
if i:=input('title is: '):
 
    w=tk.Tk()
    w.title(i)
    w.mainloop()
```